# How to organize the code for a javascript UI widget?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The web app I'm working on has several fairly complex and stateful pieces of client-side UI. I'm trying to keep things sane by organizing them into composable javascript widgets. Some of the requirements are:

1) Some of the data required to initialize the widget needs to come from the server
2) Some of the data comes from the client (based on which of a list of items is selected)
3) The state of some sections of the widget needs to be remembered when it's closed and reopened
4) The state of other sections needs to be forgotten and reset to the original setting
5) The page has to fully render very quickly, so AJAX calls need to be minimized

So, my question is, how do you organize the code for this widget? What I have currently involves sending down the HTML for the widget with some data (i.e. #1) filled in on the server side (to avoid sending down the data via an extra AJAX call). I then have a bunch of jquery code that fills in the client side stuff in an ad-hoc fashion. And then more code to reset everything back to the desired state on the second invocation. Surely there's a more declarative way to accomplish this?

Comment: why would using AJAX be slow for this approach? I have implemented just the sort of thing you're describing here, and mine is blazingly fast. I also tend to build my objects in JSON for faster transit and because I can manipulate those in JS fast... Keep that in mind.

Comment: @drachenstern, I tend to agree but it depends on the amount of data, the time it takes to generate the data, and network performances.  Most of my AJAX calls are so fast that a users wont notice if I refetch data every time it is needed, but there are enough cases where it is significantly slower that I need to decide on a case by case basis.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the sequence: (1) request the page from the server, (2) run my document.onload code, (3) decide I need more data from the server and make an AJAX call. Step 3 is a wasted round trip to the server given I could have sent that data down at step 1 (I know the client is going to need it). So how would you go about doing that? Embed a JSON object somewhere in the markup and fish it out of the DOM using jquery? Or just prepopulate the markup with the data?

Comment: @mikerobi ~ I don't think my users mind if I refetch my data either on those long calls, because I show them a pretty little spinning disk and give them the options to show hide remove widgets even while loading the background data... it's the framework of the page and the loading of the framework of the widgets themselves that's fast enough. Then again, mine is a reporting database, not a primary UI ... we do historical analysis so of course my users know that some ops take a while ...

Comment: @Abhijit Rao ~ but that's exactly the sort of thing that AJAX is good for. Hell, I do that with my db calls on my pages, instead of grouping all my calls together, cos I don't always know for sure what's coming next. I mean, sometimes I lump them together, but not always. Just try building it even with the AJAX calls and see where the sore spots are, that you need loaded before the page finishes. Mine downloads the dashboard management pane (cos that's pretty well standard across all the dashboard activities) and the document.onload code, and the basic jquery includes ... (cont)

Comment: @Abhijit Rao ~ (cont) and then the rest I load during document.onload or after the click on certain elements. I'm all for speedy display, but we don't all have to be Google Instant you know. Go check how BBC works. Go check how NYT works. Go check how /. works. All those sites are powerful and fast, but they use the same tricks you or I would, including AJAX after the page is loaded. Also, consider FB.

Comment: @drachenstern, fair enough, I may be prematurely optimizing here. But humor me for a sec. Suppose I did what you described and found that this was indeed a sore spot. How would you go about optimizing that extra call while maintaining sanity?

Comment: @Abhijit Rao ~ _I would put it in the pageload on the server instead of an ajax call._ Don't misunderstand me, I still load various things from the DB on the server, such as the user's existing dashboard tabs (I'll have to do this dashboard I did as a writeup someday so I can link to it) because it's so much easier to go ahead and get those lists right away, but I left the loading of the system to the modularity of the code ... I wrote a bit that would fetch a dashboard tab given an ID, so in my document.onload, I call that with the first dashboard tab. etc. Just code reuse, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be very happy using [Javascript MVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/).  It makes it much easier to manage the state of components, and makes it pretty easy to manage data on the client side instead of making repeated ajax calls.  Do the tutorial and I think you will be quite happy.

**EDIT**

My original answer doesn't address the page rendering speed.

If you are really worried about page rendering speed, the best solution is to render the document.  The next best solution is to not worry about the problem until the final stages of development.  It is pretty easy to optimize data loading behavior, and you will come up with much better solution after you have solidified the rest of your application design.

I have employed various techniques to improve render performance, such as cachable ajax, or injecting script blocks with data when the page is generated on the server.  Both of these approaches have given me significant performance boosts, and both were easily applied at later stages in development.

Comment: I did look at Javascript MVC, but it would have required us to change our existing build process to accommodate their include/compression mechanism. So I wanted something more lightweight.

Comment: _So I wanted something more lightweight._ roll your own? That's what I did.

Comment: Abhijit Rao, obviously I don't know what kind of work that would involve, but I have frequently made the mistake of reinventing the wheel when there was a more robust 3rd party solution, just because it wasn't a perfect fit for my needs.

Comment: Amen to that. Or I've reinvented the wheel, just so I could figure out the questions to ask, that would point me in the direction of a 3rd party solution in the first place. Sometimes not knowing what to ask is our biggest problem, yeah? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to roll your own widget, and you're going to persist the state of the widget, then assign each widget a GUID/UUID and use that as part of the "container name" of the widget (I take the last 13 digits for mine to ensure some sort of randomness. I don't maintain that it won't ever break.) You can do that part easily enough during object creation, either serverside or clientside. You can persist the GUID/UUID as the ID of the widget as well, so that isn't likely to ever change.

All this was given as part of "how do I compose the widget" *for modularity sake, especially during javascript operation* (the italicized section is what I thought was meant... further conversation leads me to believe that I may have been wrong. leaving it for posterity now)

Otherwise, see the comments above.